# Laravel 5 model event doesn't work (in production)

Tags: php, events, laravel, model, laravel-5

I've got `saving` model event in my `EventServiceProvider.php`

```
    <?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

use App\UnprotectedLead;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * The event handler mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'event.name' => [
            'EventListener',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        UnprotectedLead::saving(function($lead)
            {
                dd($lead->lead_phone);
                $lead->lead_phone_clean = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $lead->lead_phone);
            });
    }

}
```

This code work fine on localhost, but in production saving event does not work (I use dd() to check it in prod, but script didn't die)

How to debug this? Maybe `EventServiceProvider.php` didn't loaded in production?

Comment: Try to look at production environment. What hosting services are you using? Development could be done by using a server software or the built-in server. Please consider you hosting environment.

Comment: I use cloud server (I had ubunt+nginx on it). It seems the problem is that `EventServiceProvider` doesn't loads in production... I haven't got any idea why, but `dd($lead->lead_phone);` never work.

Comment: Finnaly, simple `composer update` fix problem in my case. But it will be very helpful if somebody gives some peace of advice: how to deal in this situation? How to debug (best practices), how to check if class has loaded, etc.?